# Why am I receiving messages from a group text as emails?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, sms, cellular-carriers

I'm in a group text with 2 iPhone users and 2 Android users (I have an iPhone). When I message the group, it works normally as a text on my phone, but when anyone else messages back, it automatically goes to my email (coming from their-phone-number@mms.att.net). I tried turning off my email address from who I can 'Send and Receive' messages from but it didn't do anything. This is so strange because I'm in several other group texts with both iPhone and android users and don't have this problem there. Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities don’t include operator error.

- Your cellular carrier has SMS to email enabled for your service.
- The sender of the SMS has SMS to email enabled.

I would start with your carrier. This is easy to happen since AppleID and iMessages can be your email or AppleID or cellular number and the receiving party could have your contact commingled.

- https://www.att.com/support/article/wireless/KM1061254/

Once you’re sure it’s not a carrier setting, you have to see the person doing the sending to be sure they don’t send to your email, but since you’re seeing the ATT mms email, I suspect the first two cases.

Comment: Also does your or members of your group have vendors that support group messages over SMS. Not all do